# Expand/collapse fields that are generated in an ngFor using a toggle function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have a `div` that repeats using an *ngFor. So there are multiple `div`'s on my page. Within each of these `div`'s, there several more element's that also toggle. So we have [collapsible fields within other collapsible fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayjTc.png). Each item allows the parent to collapse all children, but also the children to expand/collapse individually.

The problem is that when multiple item are generated using the *ngFor, the toggle function to expand/collapse the fields applies to all the items on the page. I want the toggle to work for only that specific item.

Here is a snippet of the HTML/AngularJS code:

```
<div padding>
  <div *ngFor="let item of ItemsList">
    <div>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            {{item.information}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            {{item.information}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            {{item.information}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            {{item.information}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a *ngIf="!expandItem" (click)="toggleItem('down')">
              <ion-icon class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></ion-icon>
            </a>
            <a *ngIf="expandItem" (click)="toggleItem('up')">
              <ion-icon class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"></ion-icon>
            </a>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      <div>
       ...
       ...
       ...
        <ion-col>
          <a *ngIf="!expandField1" (click)="toggleField1('down')">
            <ion-icon class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></ion-icon>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="expandField1" (click)="toggleField1('up')">
            <ion-icon class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"></ion-icon>
          </a>
        </ion-col>
           <ion-grid *ngIf ="expandField1 || (expandItem && expandField1)">    
          <ion-row *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItem">
            <ion-col>
              {{subItem.name}}
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
             {{subItem.name}}
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              {{subItem.name}}
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>  
        </ion-grid>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is a snippet of the toggle functions

```
toggleItem(type: any) {
        if (type == 'up') {
            this.expandItem = false;
            this.expandField1 = false;
        } else {
            this.expandItem = true;
            this.expandField1 = true;
        }
toggleField1(type: any) {
        if (type == 'up') {
            this.expandField1 = false;
        } else {
            this.expandField1 = true;
            this.expandItem = true;
    }
```

Any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use an array of expandItem and expandField1 to track opening and closing of each collapsible. For this you can use $index and then set array for it like expandItem[$index] = true for a particular collabsible on click.